# How to hide the plone 4.3 site default logo

Tags: plone

I need to to know how to replace/hide plone 4.3 default logo using my own viewlet. my viewlets.xml file is under profiles/default and i registered viewlets using generic setup like

```
<genericsetup:registerProfile
  name="default"
  title="bdr.theme"
  directory="profiles/default"
  description="Installs the bdr.theme package"
  provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
  />
```

But it does not call the viewlets.xml file to hide the default plone site plone logo. What i have to do for achieving my goal. Is it Possible in plone 4.3 or not. I m trying this  so long. Any one pls help me.

Comment: you should provide your viewlets.xml file also. And the viewlet code you are overriding it with.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Install z3c.jbot
2. Create the logo in a file called plone.app.layout.viewlets.logo.pt and move it to the jbot override directory.

Comment: If you only want to change the image, for step 2 create a `plonetheme.sunburst.skins.sunburst_images.logo.png` file instead.

Comment: No.. i need to change entire  plone site in future but for now i m trying to replace plone 4.3 default log with my image menus. One more thing is i dont want to change it from zmi. I need to do it programatically from file system. I mean without touching main_template or zmi @@manage-viewlets. Is it Possible to do in plone 4.3. I m working with viewlets now.

Comment: @OomsysPythonteam: Sometimes you say you want to hide the logo, sometimes change the logo, sometimes replace it with menues. MAKE UP YOUR MIND! Replacing it with menues makes no sense. Don't do that. Write a portlet instead. Or use one of the existing menu portlets.

Comment: its not working in our case. Pls tell some other idea to hide the default logo without going for zmi

Comment: @OomsysPythonteam: "Not working" is not an error description. It *is* working if you do it right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run run the profile in order for the viewlets.xml to apply.

Answer (score 1):

You hide the logo viewlet by opening `@@manage-viewlets`. This will show all the viewlets and you can just click the "hide" link.

After that you can export the setup from GenericSetup, and it will give you a `viewlets.xml` you can use.

Answer (score 0):

you can  change your logo using py file like
first create overrides.zcml in ..plone/product/overrides.zcmlfor replace logo

```
<browser:viewlet
    name="plone.logo"
    manager="plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IPortalHeader"
    class=".browser.home.logo"
    permission="zope2.View"
/>
```

import LogoViewlet class from plone/app/layout/viewlets/common.py
inherit that class into your class .redirect any pt file using index .now that pt file contents are replaced plone logo

```
from plone.app.layout.viewlets.common import LogoViewlet
class logo(LogoViewlet):
  index = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/logo.pt')
```