# How do I link the logo to an external site?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I would like to change the link in the Plone logo viewlet. By default it points to the Plone site root, I want to point it to a location that is not within the Plone site.

I tried writing a custom logo viewlet, but this seems very complex for such a small change. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Uhm, you have 42K rep points, you should know how to properly ask a question, right?

Comment: @STTLCU: Yes, and this is a properly asked question. It is in fact made as an example for a person who do *not* know it, and I will shortly also provide the answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939512/create-an-instance-of-one-class-from-another-class

Comment: Ok then, I've removed the -1.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694122/how-to-hide-the-plone-4-3-site-default-logo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to change the Logo link is to override the logo viewlet template. This is best done with [z3c.jbot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot).

You need to add z3c.jbot to your projects custom product, by adding it as a dependency in  `setup.py`, and also set up the configure.zcml correctly:

```
<include package="z3c.jbot" file="meta.zcml" />

<browser:jbot
    directory="templates" />
```

Don't forget to make sure you have the browser prefix added in the `<zcml>` tag.

You can now copy the `logo.pt` file from plone.app.layout to the `templates` directory in your custom product. Rename the file to `plone.app.layout.viewlets.logo.pt` and change:

```
tal:attributes="href view/navigation_root_url;
                title view/navigation_root_title"
```

To:

```
href="http://stackoverflow.com"
```

Restart the server, and the logo link has now changed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can edit it via ZMI (/manage) in portal_view_customizations. And search for the "plone.logo" view.

It should open this url in the frame:

/portal_view_customizations/zope.interface.interface-plone.logo/pt_editForm